# Create a Facebook "Like" programmatically?

Tags: iphone, facebook, mobile, facebook-like

I'd like to replicate the "Like" button functionality in an iPhone application using a native widget. The URL associated with the Like would be a product page with details on the manufacturer's website. Unfortunately, Facebook's Like Button [1] only supports the iframe version. Is there any way to have a user "Like" a URL without using the Like Button?

[1] http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 3):

There's no API to actually create a Like connection.

Comment: Has anyone used the Open Graph API method mentioned in the Developer info? The "/OBJECT_ID/likes" "write" action that "Like the given object (if it has a /likes connection)"? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: Doesn't appear to work unless you've been blessed: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=284080#p284080

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Facebook Developer info, it appears it *is* possible to Like an Open Graph Object if it already exists in the Open Graph database. Look for the "/OBJECT_ID/likes" method under the "Publishing" section of the [API Reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api). It says you can "Like the given object (if it has a /likes connection)".

But I [do not believe](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=89270) Facebook provides the ability to create NEW Open Graph objects (for, say, a webpage) programmatically. If anyone knows how to do this, I would be interested to hear about it.

There looks to be an assigned bug about not bing able to create new Graph Objects via the API: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10714

We want to have our own "Like" system with an additional "Dislike" option, and if the user "Likes" something with our system we want to create a Facebook Like in the background. It seems we will need to pre-Like all of the objects (thousands of pages!) so this won't work for us. :(